# Select for a specific number of characters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1 and have an attribute that has either 4 or 5 characters; i.e., CO-1, BY-3, CAR-1, MRT-8.

All letters are uppercase, this is in a personal GDB, and this is a string field.

I am trying to select for only the attributes that have 4 characters.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the exact ArcGIS release and the exact type of geodatabases (personal, file, enterprise; if enterprise, which RDBMS).

Answer (score 4):

From the [help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-layers/building-a-query-expression.htm#GUID-C05F4A2C-0CE4-4629-A36C-EBCB22E1B7C9)

> Use the LIKE operator (instead of the = operator) to build a partial
>   string search. For example, this expression would select Mississippi
>   and Missouri among U.S. state names:
>
> STATE_NAME LIKE 'Miss%'
>
> % means that anything is acceptable in its place: one character, a
>   hundred characters, or no character. Alternatively, if you want to
>   search with a wildcard that represents one character, use _.

Use this: Field_name LIKE '____' (four underscores)

EDIT: That was for a File Geodatabase. For a Personal Geodatabase, the answer would be [Field_name] LIKE '????'

Answer (score 4):

As your data is in a personal geodatabase you can simply use:

len([myField]) = 4

This will select all rows where the string in the field "myField" is 4 characters long.

Comment: This is a python statement, which will not work as a selection query. Selection queries use SQL style syntax.

Comment: Actually, this does work in the Select by Attributes dialog.

Comment: @Adam as I understand it the SQL style changes with the underlying database. As Slinn stated he was using a personal geodatabase this is an Access database so you can use the variant of SQL for that. This [page](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Examples-of-query-criteria-08029ed5-39f1-4900-88e3-ab473b16d94e) lists the type of commands you can use in the Where clause for an Access database.

Comment: my apologies. i didn't register the personal geodatabase comment. in that case, it works like a charm